# Can class-skills that are properties of certain weapons activate on all classes?

Tags: torchlight-2

I obtained a unique sword that haves `10% chance to cast Eviscerate`. Since **Eviscerate** is **Berzerker** class skill, could other classes cast it if they used this weapon?

[image]

Comment: To anyone coming across this question, please note that the accepted answer is probably wrong.  Look at [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/101951/11222) instead.  Berserker Eviscerate skill is different from the generic weapon proc Eviscerate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is certainly possible.

I have a 15% chance to cast **Blinding Cloud** on my righthand weapon. As an Outlander, I do not have that skill (I'm not sure as to what other class it belongs to).

[image]

Here you can see me casting it on the dummy (I was only doing regular attacks so it's most definitely the skill):

[image]

Comment: This answer is wrong.  Blinding Cloud is *NOT* a skill that is in any class skill tree.  It's just a generic weapon proc that anyone can use.

Answer (score 2):

According to a [runic forum thread](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=42345), the weapon proc "Eviscerate" is **not** the same as the Berserker Eviscerate skill, even though they share the same name.  In fact the weapon proc seems to be weaker than the Berserker's level 1, and any class can use it.

Weapon proc Eviscerate: 70% weapon DPS, no bleed

Berserker Eviscerate level 1: 88% weapon DPS, bleed for 6 seconds